# add values and merge array in object?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object

I want to create a new object by adding `count` values ​​of keys with the same name 
and then merge them.
I could use `filter` and `map` but that's for the case that I already know
what `keys` would be inside of the object. like below.

```js
obArr.filter(v => v.site === 'jelly').map(...);
```

but it needs lot of works (lot of `filter` and `map` for each `key`) and

 `key` name would be vary each time.
In this case what could be the better way?

This is the data and desired result below.

```js
const obArr = [{site: "candy", date: "2021-04-30", count: 10},
{site: "jelly", date: "2021-04-30", count: 2},
{site: "candy", date: "2021-04-29", count: 12},
{site: "jelly", date: "2021-04-29", count: 3},
{site: "candy", date: "2021-04-29", count: 5},
{site: "chocolate", date: "2021-04-29", count: 9},
{site: "jelly", date: "2021-04-29", count: 20},
{site: "chocolate", date: "2021-04-29", count: 21}];


//desired result
 const [state, setState] = useState([
    {site: 'candy', count: 27},
    {site: 'chocolate', count: 30},
    {site: 'jelly', count: '25'},
  ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count up the number of `counts` on an object (or Map) instead while iterating over the array:

```js
const obArr = [{site: "candy", date: "2021-04-30", count: 10},
{site: "jelly", date: "2021-04-30", count: 2},
{site: "candy", date: "2021-04-29", count: 12},
{site: "jelly", date: "2021-04-29", count: 3},
{site: "candy", date: "2021-04-29", count: 5},
{site: "chocolate", date: "2021-04-29", count: 9},
{site: "jelly", date: "2021-04-29", count: 20},
{site: "chocolate", date: "2021-04-29", count: 21}];

const grouped = {};
for (const { site, count } of obArr) {
  grouped[site] = (grouped[site] || 0) + count;
}
const initialState = Object.entries(grouped).map(([site, count]) => ({ site, count }));
console.log(initialState);

 // const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
```

Comment: you are So genius